# How did they find the location of Panda village?

Tags: plot-explanation, kung-fu-panda-3

In [Kung Fu Panda 3](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2267968/), How did Tigress And Kai find the location of panda village?

Comment: Good question,I remember tigress carrying the scroll about chi maybe that has the directions also

Answer (score 9):

It was never explained in the film, We just see Tigress gets the scroll while Master Shifu's chi got absorbed.

[image]

While saying "I hope you are ready Po". In the next scene she just reaches the Panda village.

[image]

We can here assume that the scroll had the hint for the location itself or maybe she just searched and reached the location.

For the case of Kai, we can just say that

"been there, done that".

As Kai was there with Grand Master Oogway in the past.

[image]

Which we see in the flashback while the team was reading the scroll, which says Kai carried injured Oogway with him and accidentally found hidden Panda village and learned to control Chi there.